# maven multimodule not keep the mapping module when import to new eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, module, maven, workspace

I created a maven multi-module project by using eclipse and m2eclipse plugin:
First: i created a parent project by using eclipse (choose menu\New\Maven project), then right click on that project and click New\Other\MavenModule). I have 2 modules.
by using that way, on the project Explorer panel, i can see one parent project and 2 module like this:

```
  - parent
         - module 1
         - module 2
  - module 1 (mapping from module 1 that stay inside parent)
  - module 2 (mapping from module 2, whatever you change here will be reflect to module 2 that stay inside parent)
```

I like this way, because i can treat the modules like a real eclipse project, i can right click on the module and do Clean or Build.

But now the problem happened when i create a new workspace and import the parent project into new workspace (i still using the same eclipse), the module mapping disappear. now in the new workspace, what i can see is:

```
-parent
      - module 1
      - module 2
```

The new look is so inconvenient. i dont have availability to treat the module like the real project any more.

My question is how to fix that issue? what i want is when import to a new workspace, the project still have the mapping modules go along with.

Answer (score 0):

go to workspace parent folder try running this

```
    mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

see here what it does: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html

> **eclipse:eclipse**
>
> *Full name*: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8:eclipse
>
> *Description*:
>   Generates the following eclipse configuration files:
>
> - .project and .classpath files
> - .setting/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs with project specific compiler settings
> - various configuration files for WTP (Web Tools Project), if the parameter wtpversion is set to a valid version (WTP configuration is not generated by default)
>
> **If this goal is run on a multiproject root, dependencies between modules will be configured as direct project dependencies in Eclipse** (unless useProjectReferences is set to false).